# Выгрузка данных в Excel Python

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать. Есть список данных A , B и С. Необходимо, чтоб данные A попали в названия листов (причем каждый раз при запуске скрипта выполнялась проверка, если такое название или нет, если нет, то добавляется новый лист). Далее значения B и C записывались построчно, причем при запуске скрипта добавлялась новая строка. Пример как начал делать и ниже скрины, что на выходе.

```
import datetime
import pandas
с = datetime.date.fromordinal(datetime.date.today().toordinal()-1).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
a = ['1', '2']
b = ['test', 'test2']
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('1.xlsx')
data_frame = pandas.DataFrame({'дата':с, 'Значение1': a, 'Значение2': b})
data_frame.to_excel(writer, 'a', index=False)
writer.save()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Может даже схему какую-то нарисовать что куда должно попадать

Comment: Добавил скрины что должно быть на выходе. Может так понятнее будет